# Is it normal to have same user logged in twice but from another TTY?

Tags: macos, command-line, security, user-account

I don't know if this is something that is in macOS, but in Linux I normally see only one user if I run the `who` and `w` command.

**Is it normal to have same user logged in twice but from another TTY?**

I don't know where the second account with the same username came from.

```
jen-air:~ jen$ who
jen     console  Aug 22 20:56 
jen     ttys000  Aug 23 08:39 

jen-air:~ jen$ w
 8:43  up 11:47, 2 users, load averages: 1.51 1.60 1.70
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
jen     console  -                Wed20   11:46 -
jen     s000     -                 8:39       - w
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a little more information about what is happening, from a lower level Unix perspective. It's long and goes beyond what you asked, but might be interesting to you or someone else passing this page.

If you look at the `w` command's manual (`man w`), it says that "The w utility prints a summary of the current activity on the system, including what each user is doing." That's a little vague, and a little misleading. Specifically what `w` does is to tell you about current *logins*. Logins are recorded in a file named `/var/run/utmpx`. There are common library methods for updating `utmpx` entries, so that every program that needs to record or remove a login uses the same procedure.

`w` reads the `utmpx` file using those common library routines and displays information about current login sessions, along with the *foreground process*. A login session can be doing many things at once, but only one program is in the foreground. All others are background, which is what happens when you put an `&` on your command or press `control-Z` while a program runs in a terminal.

A login session is created when you log in to your computer on the built-in display. If you have user switching enabled, a login is recorded for each user, and remains active until logout. And if you remote login (e.g. with `ssh`), a login is recorded for that. Each of these should appear in `w`'s output.

Most terminal applications, including Terminal.app and iTerm, as well as `xterm` if you're using X11.app, are able to create login shells in a window or tab. When you create a new window in one of these applications, you can get another login session, which appears as another line in `w`. But these applications don't *necessarily* create login shells! Whether a new window/tab is a login shell is usually controlled in the preferences. For example, in iTerm2, you can choose in Preferences > Profiles > General > Command whether to launch a login shell or some other program. If you just put "bash" there, you'll get a shell, but it won't be a *login* shell.

So what's the difference? It's subtle, but useful to know about.

There's a good discussion of login shells vs. regular shells here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell. But we can summarize as: a login shell is started as the first process after something sets up a login in `utmpx`. A non-login shell can be run any time by any program, but is not the first process after an entry in `utmpx`. (More technically, a login shell is the lead process in a process group. The fact that it usually has a `utmpx` entry is descriptive, not necessary.)

If your shell is `bash`, as most are, every instance of it reads and runs the `.bashrc` file. When `bash` runs as a login shell, it also reads and runs the `.bash_profile` and `.profile` files. Those files can contain instructions that should happen only for all new sessions. That's the main practical thing to know about login shells. That, and login shells appear in `w`.

Here's an experiment to illustrate. Open a new Terminal window, and run `w`. You should see something like:

```
11:57  up 7 days, 59 mins, 5 users, load averages: 3.58 3.53 3.91
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
dgc      console  -                16Aug18 7days -
dgc      s000     -                11:57       - w
```

`s000` is the name of the terminal that you're running `w` in. It exists on the filesystem at `/dev/ttys000`. Usually there's a one to one relation between login shells and terminals, but not always.

Now open a new Terminal window. Switch back to the first one, and run `w` again.

```
12:09  up 7 days,  1:11, 5 users, load averages: 5.35 4.35 4.05
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
dgc      console  -                16Aug18 7days -
dgc      s000     -                11:38       - w
dgc      s001     -                11:57       - -bash
```

You see a new login on `s001` — `/dev/ttys001` — that's running `-bash`. That hyphen at the beginning is a convention telling you that bash is running as a login shell. There's no foreground program in that terminal, so `w` shows you the shell itself.

Now switch back to your second window and run `bash`. What do you expect to happen?

```
12:13  up 7 days,  1:14, 5 users, load averages: 5.61 5.07 4.41
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
dgc      console  -                16Aug18 7days -
dgc      s000     -                11:38       - w
dgc      s001     -                11:57       - bash
```

The hyphen is gone. That's because the same login session (terminal) is now running, in the foreground, a shell that isn't a login shell. It's a *child* of the original `-bash`. If you flip back and type `exit` to quit the child bash, you'll see the `-bash` again.

Finally, note the `console` login. That one will never change in ordinary use. It's running the desktop/window system usually. If you turn on your Mac and *don't* log in, but then you `ssh` in from another computer, you won't see that line at all. It will always appear idle, and will always appear to be running nothing — except with the hyphen, because it's a login session.

When a program that created a login session ends that login, it goes back and removes the entry from `utmpx` using the common library methods for it. And because `utmpx` resides in the `/var/run` directory, it gets automatically removed whenever your computer reboots — so if you suddenly powered off your Mac while logged in, you don't continue to see fake logins forever.

Answer (score 12):

The default Terminal app in macOS opens up a second login so when `who` or `w` command is executed the Terminal app, there's a second login.

Depending on your environment and the Terminal app, some terminal emulation apps like [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com) will show only one login.

Answer (score 10):

**Yes** it is normal.

Console is your desktop login and the second login appears after you open a Terminal window. In-fact if you have more than one Terminal window/tab open, an entry is shown corresponding to each.

Comment: It's a little surprising that there's no setting in Preferences to control whether the window is a login or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's normal. If you use a terminal multiplexer like tmux or screen, each 'tab' will be a separate user session.